# Tradução de texto em sinalização de respostas antigas de baixa qualidade

Tags: bug, status-aceito, tradução, internacionalização

Me deparei com mais uma string que não foi devidamente traduzida:

[image: This answer has been on the site for quite a while now; it probably won't benefit from commentary. if you think it could be fixed, go back and leave a comment explaining the problem.]

Para quem não sabe, essa tela é algo (felizmente) bem raro de surgir, só a vi umas 4 ou 5 vezes até hoje. Essa tela só aparece na fila de análise para respostas de baixíssima qualidade que sejam muito antigas. Como não toleramos respostas de baixíssima qualidade por aqui e procuramos eliminá-las rapidamente, são pouquíssimas as que sobrevivem e acabam indo parar na fila de análise apenas muito tardiamente (essa do exemplo foi postada há 4 anos).

Eis a mensagem a ser traduzida:

> This answer has been on the site for quite a while now; it probably won't benefit from commentary. If you think it could be fixed, go back and leave a comment explaining the problem.

Sugiro essa tradução:

> Esta resposta já está no site há bastante tempo e provavelmente não iria se beneficiar de um comentário. Se mesmo assim, você acha que ela ainda pode ser consertada, volte e deixe um comentário explicando o problema.